# \widetilde from mtpro2 not working in \section

Tags: math-mode, errors, mtpro

I am using the `\widetilde` macro provided by the `mtpro2` package. The macro works fine in an usual paragraph, but it raises an error if used in in a `\section`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
\section{$\widetilde{O}$}
$\widetilde{O}$
\end{document}
```

And the error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@widetilde ...extfont 3=\MTEXE@ }\else \def \TD@ 
                                                  {\textfont 3=\MTEXA@ }\fi ...
l.6 \section{$\widetilde{O}$}
```

A similar error appears for the `\widehat` macro.

Comment: Try `\protect\widetilde`... but I can't test this, since I don't have the fonts

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

The commands `\widecheck`, `\widehat` and `\widetilde` are defined in terms of `\mathpalette`; precisely, `\widetilde` is `\mathpalette\@widetilde` (similarly for the other two) so they should be made robust.

Not that `\mathpalette` is fragile by itself, but it's better if the `.aux` file reports `\widetilde` instead of the full expansion of `\mathpalette\@widetilde`, even if it didn't raise an error.

The method is easy

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify\widetilde
\robustify\widehat
\robustify\widecheck

\begin{document}

\section{$\widetilde{O}\widehat{O}\widecheck{O}$}

\end{document}
```

### History

The LaTeX kernel, could not make robust that many commands, because of memory limitation. So the `\protect` mechanism was used. In recent years, memory started to no longer be a problem and `\MakeRobust` was added to the kernel (instead of having to be requested with `fixltx2e`).

How does a LaTeX robust command work? If one does `\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[<n>]{...}`, LaTeX will define both `\foo` and `\foo•` (where `•` stands for a space in the command name). The former is simply a shorthand for `\protect\foo•` and it's the latter that does the real work.

Until a few years ago, `\widetilde` was not defined as a robust command, so an input such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\MakeRobust\widetilde
```

was a good way to make `\widetilde` suitable for usage in moving arguments.

Until the LaTeX kernel made a huge step in robustifying many more commands, among which the wide math accents. Good! No need of `\MakeRobust` any longer!

Well, almost. Unfortunately, `mtpro2` still does `\def\widetilde#1{...}` and this only redefines the “surface” command `\widetilde`, but leaves `\widetilde•` untouched. But now `\widetilde` is not robust and it will fail in moving arguments. So we apply again `\MakeRobust\widetilde`, isn't that easy?

Sorry, no: `\MakeRobust` has no way to know how a command was defined and it checks for the existence of the “inner” command (with a trailing space in its name). If it finds it, then it thinks that the command is already robust and does nothing.

So with TeX Live 2020 or later the previously suggested workaround with `\MakeRobust\widetilde` ceased to work.

Since `\robustify` uses a very different protection mechanism, one can get around the problem. Not a big deal: `etoolbox` is a well-tested and maintained package.

Otherwise one has to remove the “inner version” before applying `\MakeRobust`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ReallyMakeRobust}[1]{%
  \count@ =\escapechar \escapechar =`\\
  \expandafter\let\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\space\endcsname\relax
  \escapechar=\count@
  \MakeRobust#1%
}
\makeatother

\ReallyMakeRobust\widetilde
\ReallyMakeRobust\widehat
\ReallyMakeRobust\widecheck

\begin{document}

\section{$\widetilde{O}\widehat{O}\widecheck{O}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to stop working in TeXLive'21.  One now gets an `Undefined control sequence.` error with the file above.

Comment: @TeXApprentice I changed the code. Not really the best solution, as it introduce a dependency, but avoiding the dependency would require really ugly code.